# How to figure out what the base case for a recursive Square root guessing program

Tags: java, recursion

The problem I'm working on is this:

> The following method was known to the ancient Greeks for computing
>   square roots. Given a value x > 0 and a guess g for the square root, a
>   better guess is (g + x/g) / 2. Write a recursive helper method public
>   static squareRootGuess(double x, double g). If g^2 is approximately
>   equal to x, return g, otherwise, return squareRootGuess with the
>   better guess. Then write a method public static squareRoot(double x)
>   that uses the helper method.

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing here. I don't believe my base case is correct for this function. I don't have a good grasp on what exactly the problem is asking.

```
public class rootchecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(squareRoot(125));
        System.out.println(squareRoot(4));
    }

    // helper
    public static double squareRoot(double x)
    {
        return squareRootGuess(x, x-1);
    }

    // recursive
    public static double squareRootGuess(double x, double g)
    {
        if (x == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            double ans = (g + (x/g) / 2);
            return squareRootGuess(x-1, ans);
        }
    }


}
```

**Update:**

I have fixed my base case. My code is now as follows:

```
public class rootchecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(squareRoot(125));
        System.out.println(squareRoot(4));
    }

    // helper
    public static double squareRoot(double x)
    {
        return squareRootGuess(x, x-1);
    }

    // recursive
    public static double squareRootGuess(double x, double g)
    {
        if (Math.abs(Math.sqrt(x) - g) < 0.001)
        {
            return g;
        }
        else
        {
            double ans = (g + (x/g) / 2);
            return squareRootGuess(x, ans);
        }
    }


}
```

Continuing on for the problem, is my logic correct for the else statement? I don't believe it is, considering I get a Stack Overflow Error.

Comment: It says in the text you wrote out when you should return g  `If g^2 is approximately equal to x, return g`

Comment: So it's simply `if (x == Math.sqrt(2.0));`?

Comment: They said approximately equal, so I would do `if (Math.abs(Math.sqrt(x) - g) < 0.001)`

Comment: Well you need a definition of approximately. Can you be within 1 whole number within 0.5 within 0.000000001 what is the approximation?

Comment: You put your closing parentheses in the wrong place. It can just be `(g + x / g) / 2`. Because of order of operations, there's no need for parentheses around `x / g`.

Comment: You set ans to (g + (x/g) / 2). You want (g + (x/g))/2

Comment: I fixed it now. I still get a stack overflow error when I run the program, though.

Comment: Disregard that: I typed it in wrong. Output is `11.180550580098988` and `2.0000102400262145`.

Comment: @Matt Woo! That means it worked. If you want to output something nicer, use `System.out.printf("%.3f%n", squareRoot(125));` So that it rounds to 3 decimal places.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please make sure that this question gets properly retired.  Either post and accept an answer, or delete it.  Since this is merely a misplaced parenthesis, I'm in favor of deleting it -- no added value to StackOverflow archives.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was instead of going with the "<" in the if statement I changed it to "<=" and it worked.

```
public static double squareRootGuess(double x, double g)
    {
        if (Math.abs(Math.sqrt(x) - g) <= 0.001)
        {
            return g;
        }
        else
        {
            double ans = (g + (x/g) / 2);
            return squareRootGuess(x, ans);
        }
    }
```